# To set exception recipients email in environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception-notifier

As shown in code below, recipient's mails are hard-coded, how can I set them in environment variable

```
  Example::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
    :email => {
      email_prefix: "[Error] ",
      sender_address: %{"Exception Notifier" <exception@example.com>},
      exception_recipients: %w{example@example.com example2@example.com}
  }
```

I've tried `exception_recipients: ENV['mail']` `%w{ENV['mail']}` `"%w{#{ENV['mail']}}"`, but none works, it gives syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the format you pass the `mail` variable in`. I'd probably go with semicolon separated list of email addresses.

```
ENV["mail"] # => "example@example.com;example2@example.com"
```

And then in the configuration:

```
exception_recipients: String(ENV["mail"]).split(";")
```

Notice the use of `String` to make sure it won't blow up on you if the key is not set (`nil`).